# I can't retrieve logged user's information to form2

Tags: vb.net

As the title says, I can not get the logged user's information to form2. I'm using access database.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public id, pw, bal, nme As String

    Private Sub CardBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CardBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.CardBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.KartDataSet)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        id = Card_IDTextBox.Text
        pw = PasswordTextBox.Text

        Dim login = CardTableAdapter.IDPW(id, pw)

        If login Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Check ID or PW")
        Else
            MsgBox("Welcome, now you are connecting.")
            Form2.Show()
            bal = Form2.BalanceTextBox.Text
            nme = Form2.UserTextBox.Text
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to store passwords in a database. Rather Hash them. Also You are not putting anyting into Form2.BalanceTextBox.Text .  You are merely assigning the value of that textbox (guessing an empty one) to a variable.

Comment: What Code is in the Load event of Form2?

Comment: Thank you for answer The White Wolf! I'm very appreciated. It is only for my term project, so our lecturer told us to do it like that.

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf i know i'm not even a beginner, i'm just a creep :( these are my form2 codes; id = Form1.Card_IDTextBox.Text
        pw = Form1.PasswordTextBox.Text
        bal = Me.BalanceTextBox.Text
        nme = Me.UserTextBox.Text

Answer (score 0):

If the code in your comment ..

```
id = Form1.Card_IDTextBox.Text
pw = Form1.PasswordTextBox.Text 
bal = Me.BalanceTextBox.Text 
nme = Me.UserTextBox.Text
```

is in your form2.Load handler, when you call

```
Form2.Show()
```

the code above will never run. You need to move it into your `Form2.Shown` event. Like this ..

```
Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    id = Form1.Card_IDTextBox.Text
    pw = Form1.PasswordTextBox.Text 
    bal = Me.BalanceTextBox.Text 
    nme = Me.UserTextBox.Text
End Sub
```

The `.Load` event will only trigger when an instance of the Form2 class is created. Visual Studio create code behind the scenes that automatically creates a default instance of Form2 when the program is started. Of course at that point, your textboxes etc have no values in them, so any code like yours above will be useless in the `Form2.Load` handler :-)

Comment: id = Form1.Card_IDTextBox.Text
Shouldn't it be the other way around?  Form1.Card_IDTextBox.Text = id      After all the OP wants to fill the textbox.

Comment: not according to their last comment  under the question